# can a finalized/closed dvd be modified?

Tags: dvd, dvd-burning

Is there a method to change data or burn new data to a dvd that is already closed/finalized?
My question is only about the iso9660 format.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a DVD±R (and not DVD±RW), you cannot change/add data in it. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finalize_%28optical_discs%29)

Comment: That article isn't the full story, because there is a way to write CD-Rs (not RWs) so you can add more data.  IIRC, it's incompatible with older hardware.  I don't know whether there is an equivalent for DVD Rs.